# How to convert a column from Geometry to Geography in SQL Server 2012 Spatial table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, spatial, geography

I have 2 tables (area & location) and I want to check the lat & long co-ordinate in one table is present in with in the area of the another table.

Table name: AREA
Columns:
OBJECTID   (int),
AREA_NAME  (varchar(50)), 
GEOM       (**Geometry**)

Table name: LOCATION
Columns:
ID         (int),
LATITUDE   (varchar(50)),
LONGITUDE  (varchar(50))

Sample data from Area table:

```
SELECT OBJECTID
,AREA
,GEOM
,GEOM.STAsText() 
FROM AREA
```

[image: AREA TABLE]

```
SELECT 
ID
,LATITUDE 
,LONGITUDE  
FROM LOCATION
```

[image: LOCATION TABLE]

I want to check whether the location (i.e, latitude and longitude co-ordinates)  is with in the area or not. The area table is having a column GEOMETRY column.
So I would like to convert this geometry column to geography column. Once I convert to geography, I can check whether the location is within the area or not using STIntersects().

But when I try to convert, I get an error as Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.

```
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(CAST(GEOM AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 4326) FROM AREA
```

Full Error message:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 70 A .NET Framework error occurred
>   during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
>   System.FormatException: 24201: **Latitude values must be between -90 and
>   90 degrees.** System.FormatException:     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeographyValidator.ValidatePoint(Double x,
>   Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y,
>   Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x,
>   Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.CoordinateReversingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double
>   x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseLineStringText()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePolygonText()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type,
>   Int32 srid)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type,
>   SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType
>   type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid) .

I'm new to this sql server spatial data. Could someone guide me to do this task? Thanks! :)

Update on 20170414: [Here](https://ibb.co/hjBMi5) is the sample data from AREA & LOCATION table after I have converted the lat&long co-ordinates to Geometry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your area is in web mercator coordinates, not latitude and longitude.
In mercator coordinates are counted in meters from (0,0), not degrees.

Try convert lat lon to web mercator, then create geometry point using new coordinates,

Here is code exapmle (JS):

```
var degrees2meters = function(lon,lat) {
        var x = lon * 20037508.34 / 180;
        var y = Math.log(Math.tan((90 + lat) * Math.PI / 360)) / (Math.PI / 180);
        y = y * 20037508.34 / 180;
        return [x, y]
}

x= -77.035974
y = 38.898717

console.log(degrees2meters(x,y))

// should result in: -8575605.398444, 4707174.018280
```

https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/871897

Comment: I have converted the lat & long points to geometry and then trying to to check whether the area contains the lat & long points. But I get no result. [Here](https://ibb.co/hjBMi5) is an sample data from Area and Location. When I look at the POINT & POLYGON data, the polygon area doesn't contain these points. Is there any issue in how i have converted the lat&long points to geometry?

Comment: Do you try solution #2? Intersect area column with polygon before converting to georgaphy.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the #2.

Comment: I've comletly rewrite my answer